# C++ While Loop Clarification

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

This is the coding I have for my while loop, all I want is for the program to ask the user if they want to re run the program. The are supposed to enter (Y/N). However each time I run my program it just continually runs the main() function, even if I enter a N or n character for my ans variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
cin>>ans;

        while((ans !='N')||(ans !='n')) {
        return main();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: A C++ program must not call `main`. Your program is ill-formed.

Comment: `return main();` Huh??

Comment: This is only a portion of my program, I want it to call back to the main function so it re-runs the same function from the beginning. Is there another way of doing this without calling the main function?

Comment: Wrap all of the code in main in a loop.

Comment: *"This is only a portion of my program"* - Don't do that. Post complete examples, but minimise them such that only the problem remains.

Comment: This is all the information that is needed to figure out my problem I believe, I changed the || operator to && and it seemed to work so now when I enter N or an n my program terminates, otherwise it re runs the main function.

Comment: This question is ill judged - Perhaps a rethink

Comment: @EdHeal _"This question is ill judged"_ Not really. It was asked in a very bad form perhaps. `return main();` is a certain _no go_.

Comment: Perhaps you are right - but it is ....

Comment: @EdHeal I was trying to ask the user if they want to re-run the program. I wanted it to run the main function unless the user enters a N or an n.

Comment: @Beez then you'll have to write another function that `main` calls and call that again. You can't call `main` in C++, it's against the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition `(ans !='N')||(ans !='n')` is always `true`. Either `ans` is not `N` or `ans` in not `n`. One side is always `true`. Change it to `while (ans !='N')&&(ans !='n')` then your loop terminates if `ans`is equal `N` or `ans` is equal `n`.
Note `A || B` is the same as `!(!A && !B)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your while statement, the "||" means "or". As long as one of those conditions are true, the while statement will keep running. You need to use an "and" statement, "&&".

Answer (score 0):

#### Proper way

```
int askAgain() {
    do {
        // Do your work
        // But never call main(), people will laugh
        cin>>ans;
    } while((ans !='N') && (ans !='n'));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to accomplish what you're seeking to do. Even though it may be possible to make it work with return main(), it's highly inefficient.

One way to have a loop that runs until the user enters a key ('N' in this example) would be to:

```
int main()
{
    char ans = '?';

    while (ans != 'N' && ans != 'n')
    {
        cin >> ans;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The intention is to continually prompt the user to enter a value once it doesn't match the condition. I've also set 'ans' to a value '?' so that on the first run of the loop it won't encounter an error. You could also turn this into a: do-while loop and remove the initialization to accomplish the same thing.

Hope that explains it enough for you.